# How to override riverpod providers for a page route that has been generated with GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-go-router, riverpod-generator

I am trying to override a riverpod provider for a specifig GoRouter route.

This is my current setup and I am still getting `UnimplementedError` in the `AssessPage`

The provider I want to override

```dart
@Riverpod(dependencies: [])
AssessmentEvent currentEvent(CurrentEventRef ref) => throw UnimplementedError();
```

Creating a ProviderScope for the Page

```dart
class AssessRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const AssessRoute(this.assessmentId, this.$extra);
  static const path = 'assess';
  final AssessmentEvent $extra;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        currentEventProvider.overrideWithValue($extra),
      ],
      child: const AssessPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Navigating to the `AssessPage`

```dart
   await AssessRoute(item.event).push(context);
```